# Confused at to why this arraylist code is not working? Includes alist.removeLast();

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

Anyone know what this code does?

I am very confused, and also it doesn't work for some reason even though its in my textbook.

Here is my array list:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();


  while(!alist.isEmpty()){
      alist.removeLast();
  }
```

The alist.removeLast(); piece of code has an error in it

Im not sure what this piece of code is supposed to do and how to get it to work.

Comment: Please add the java tag

Comment: *What* error is there? If you do not know what that piece of code is supposed to do, how can you know it is not doing exactly what it is supposed to do?

Comment: I'm confused.  ArrayList does not have a `removeLast()` method...

Comment: Perhaps reading the Javadoc for `ArrayList` might shine some light on the mystery? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html (Hint: there's no such method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this exact code is in your textbook, then your textbook is wrong.  `ArrayList.removeLast()` does not exist.  However, `LinkedList.removeLast()` does exist.

And it looks like this method is taking a really strange approach to emptying the List.

Comment: So how would you empty the list? any idea?

Comment: @user2132630: If this is from your textbook, then this is probably part of a homework.  Try looking at the Oracle doc Brian Roach posted above, and see which method would do what you need.

Comment: Hey @david, do you know what !alist.isEmpty() does? 0_0 the ! is some kind of logic, and i guess the isEmpty checcks if it is empty?

Comment: @user2132630: If you don't know what the `!` does, you should start looking at some Java tutorials (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).  For `isEmpty()`, you are correct, and the Javadoc for ArrayList explains that (docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

[`removeLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast%28%29) is a method of [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). To remove the last element of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), use:

```
arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);
```